# vb.net AxShockwaveFlash dynamically created error

Tags: vb.net, flash, axshockwaveflash

I've got an error while creating an `AxShockwaveFlash` control in VB.NET , when I load a movie , an error appears :

> Exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.AxHost+InvalidActiveXStateException' was thrown
>   .

This is my code :

```
Dim animFlashObject As New AxShockwaveFlash
Me.Controls.Add(animFlashObject)
animFlashObject.Movie = "D:\Dé-compilateur de .d2p\data\swf\9014.swf"
animFlashObject.EmbedMovie = True
animFlashObject.Play()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to answer this, keep in mind that my English is not that good.

I think the problem lays with your "url" to the .swf file.
Try putting your .swf file in another folder, example: "C:\anotherfolder\movie.swf" it's bin a while since I used vb.net, but I think this is it.

Goodluck